# what does [0] mean in django query?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

for example when I want to filter a query, why should I write [0] at the end?

```
      order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(
               item=product,
               user=self.request.user,
               ordered=False
            )[0]
```

when I don't add [0] at the end it raises an error something like that:

```
Field 'id' expected a number but got <QuerySet [<OrderItem: OrderItem object (5)>]>.
```

or in another situation when I don't add [0] at the end, it raises this error:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queryset as iterable so you can access its elements by index (like a list). In this code:

```
order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(
           item=product,
           user=self.request.user,
           ordered=False
        )
```

You will get a Queryset and `[0]` at the end will pick first element in it. Like normal iterable.

You can replace `[0]` with `.first()` like:

```
order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(
               item=product,
               user=self.request.user,
               ordered=False
            ).first()
```

and it will return first element from Queryset (or `None` if Queryset is empty).

If you are sure that only one objects will match query you can use `get()`:

```
order_item = OrderItem.objects.get(
           item=product,
           user=self.request.user,
           ordered=False
        )
```

Comment: There's a slight differernce. If the query matches no objects,  `.first()` returns `None` (successfully) whereas `[0]` throws an `IndexError` becaues one cannot index an empty list.